# Bottom-fixed element disappearing on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, viewport

Please take look at the following page on mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wide">WIDE</div>
  <div id="fixed">FIXED</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wide {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
}

#fixed {
  background-color: green;
  position:fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

The fixed element is there at the bottom right as expected. However, when you increase the width of the wide div **past your device viewport width** (in css pixels), the fixed div disappears.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Further details:

- An easy way to test this is to use mobile view in Chrome DevTools, and change the width directly under Elements > Styles.
- Close to the limiting width you see the fixed div cut off horizontally.
- Same thing without `meta viewport`, but the threshold will be at the default viewport width 980px.
- Tried combinations of `height: 100%` and `min-height:100%` on `html` and `body` with no success.
- No issues in desktop browser.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here.

I am not sure why the fixed div is not rendered. It is somehow related to the fact that the 'wide' div overflows the body element, causing the view to be zoomed out and the body ending up less tall than the viewport. I still believe that the mobile browser should show the fixed element just like the desktop browser does.

My fix: wrap the wide content in a container element with `overflow-x: scroll`. This works well on mobile, the fixed div is shown again and the wide content can be swiped across.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ctnr">
    <div id="wide">WIDE</div>
  </div>
  <div id="fixed">FIXED</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#ctnr {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#wide {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
}

#fixed {
  background-color: green;
  position:fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you but I added `display: table-cell;` to #wide.
This way your div won't exceed the maximum width.

Comment: Nice find. Unfortunately it does not help when you have actual wide content in the first div (put a long text in there).

Comment: It works for me, here is an example: (maybe I undertand your question wrong) https://jsfiddle.net/p5uns2sk/

Comment: OK, I see. But your text just wraps, it will not make the div wider. I need to have some real wide content in there which will not shrink or wrap. Btw I was testing with a single long word, no spaces -- hence the different results.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, I could fix it with adding pixels to the bottom. Like this:
`bottom: 30px;` (depends on the lenght of your content)

Comment: Yes, it helps. But just a little bit, depending on content width, as you say. It still does not explain however WHY the fixed div gets cut off.